# "Table not found" exception when trying to read from DSE using Spark SQL

Tags: java, maven-3, datastax-enterprise, apache-spark-sql

I have DSE 4.6 installed on a server. I have created a repository and a table. I have also inserted some data into the table. I am trying to read the data using Spark SQL but I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Table Not Found: test.table3
```

This is my Java code:

```
import com.datastax.bdp.spark.DseSparkConfHelper;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSchemaRDD;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = DseSparkConfHelper.enrichSparkConf(new SparkConf()).setAppName("Simple App").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaSQLContext sqlContext = new JavaSQLContext(sc);

        JavaSchemaRDD data = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM test.table3");
        System.out.println(data.count());
    }
}
```

I am using Maven to manage dependencies. This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>cassandra-data-retriever</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/projectrepo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax</groupId>
        <artifactId>bdp</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

EDIT: The table does in fact exist. Here is output from cqlsh:

```
 cqlsh> DESCRIBE TABLE test.table3 
CREATE TABLE table3 (
id int,
birth_date timestamp,
name text,
PRIMARY KEY ((id))
) WITH
bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
comment='' AND
dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
index_interval=128 AND
read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
replicate_on_write='true' AND
populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
default_time_to_live=0 AND
speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

EDIT2: I can also read the data using cqlsh:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM test.table3;

id | birth_date               | name
----+--------------------------+-------
  1 | 1970-01-15 07:48:54+0100 | Peter

(1 rows)
```

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, the error message says "table not found". Have you actually created table3 in schema test? Can you show the output from cqlsh of desc table test.table3?

Comment: No problem. You are trying to help. I have added cqlsh output above.

Comment: Can you select from the table in cqlsh? Trying to narrow down to the driver.

Comment: @phact Yes, I can select. Added output to post.